# which Virtualization Software work best on AMD?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Which Virtualization Software has been optimised for AMD Phenom II X4 945 Processor?  AMD Phenom II processors support Virtualization Technology.

I have tried Oracle VM VirtualBox and installed Ubuntu. It was really slow and choppy.

Comment: What amount of RAM did you give that virtual machine, and did you use a fixed single file virtual disk, and reserve the space all at once? This will give the best performance, I recommend 1.5GB+ minimum for the RAM, depending on the purpose.

Comment: In addition to @MDMoore313's question. What GUI did you run? The current default GUI for Ubuntu requires **masses** of 3D processing power for smooth running - every bit as much as Windows. What Graphics processor do you have? Are you using the VirtualBox tools in the guest OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use VirtualBox to run (k)ubuntu and WinXP/Win7 virtual guests almost everyday, even on my old HP laptop (4GB RAM), and it actually works quite smooth using the processor’s HW virtualization. I usually recommend VirtualBox and myself use the following setup:

- around 20GB (virtual, self-increasing) file system per machine
- 1 GB of RAM per virtual machine
- 64-128 KB graphics memory per VM
- hardware virtualization ON
- Guest Additions installed in the guest (important)
- for (k)ubuntu also 3D graphics acceleration set to ON (NOT "2D"!)

This gives me a quite acceptable performance, even when running VirtualBox and the VMs from an attached 500 GB USB2.0 harddisk on a 4 GB RAM laptop. With TWO VMs running simultaneously under Win7 …

Good luck!